# Perl - Regex replace negative

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to replace a complete string, using regex if not found.
I'm using this to replace if found:

```
my $var = "This apple is white";
$var =~ s/(.*)pple(.*)/No apples for you!/i;
```

Now I want to invert it, so if pple is not found, then it should replace everything with "No apples for you!".

I tried to invert with this

```
my $var = "This apple is white";
$var =~ s/(.*)^pple(.*)/No apples for you!/i;
```

but I could find out how to make it working.

Comment: you can use `!~` for this

Comment: @loldop that's an answer right there :p

Comment: @Mattrition yeah, i know, but it is short answer and i don't have enough time to tell about good books, that i recommended to beginner and good sites and other stuff. I just spot him about `!~` - another Perl beauty and mystery ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Replace everything" is exactly equal to "assign a new value". So you don't need a replace operator ('s///'), when simple match should suffice:

```
my $var = 'This apple is white';
if ($var !~ /\bapple\b/i) {
  $var = 'No apples for you!';
}
```

I've changed a regex a bit: added `/i` modifier, making the pattern case-insensitive (to capture both 'Apple' and 'apple'; I suppose that's why in the original post it was 'pple'), and wrapped the word with `\b` (to prevent matching on 'Applegate' and 'pineapple').

UPDATE: I think that's the clearest solution, but technically it's still possible to do without `if`:

```
$var =~ s/^(?!.*\bapple\b.*).*$/No apples for you/i;
```

Here's a simple test:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;

my @fruit_strings = (
    'This apple is white',
    'This pineapple is violet',
    'This Apple is a company',
    'This pear is green');

for (@fruit_strings) {
     s/^(?!.*\bapple\b.*).*$/No apples for you/i;
     say;
}
```

Note that if your strings are multiline, you'd have to add `/m` modifier to the regex.

Also I'd suggest reading these two tutorials - [Perl regular expressions quick start](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) and [Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Hey there, I don't want to use if. Is it directly possible in my regex?

Comment: @PeterI, here is how you described what you want to do: "**if** pple is not found, then it should replace everything with "No apples for you!".

Comment: The replacement operator is used to replace something that matched with something else.  "Replacement" has no meaning when there wasn't a match.  You could replace the `if` statement with a shorter, equivalent expression, but it would be foolish to try to do this directly within a regex.

Comment: Thank you @raina77ow, Your Update is what I exactly needed. -- And how about the usage of !~  -- Googling that seems not easy ^_^

Comment: @PeterI Added links to the official (kinda) documentation for regexes in Perl. The first one mentions `!~`, the second concentrates more on patterns (but is definitely a must-read for any Perler, imo).